# wordpress search with synonym letters for arabic language

Tags: wordpress, search

How can I have WordPress search different letters in Arabic? For example, `أ-ا-إ` are the same letters but in different formats. E.g. can I search WordPress for something like "world" > "?orld" (using REGEX or similar)?

Comment: You might want to ask in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you may be looking for something like [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/). It should allow you to easily search WordPress, Arabic or otherwise.

It has support for the WPML multi-language and Polylang plugins, too.